# How do I counter Bloodseeker mid?

Tags: dota-2, dota

I've been playing Dota for at least a year and always seem to run into trouble laning mid against a *good* Bloodseeker (one that can last-hit/deny well).  Even if I try to harass him, he will STILL last-hit/deny his way through the damage and eventually reach a quick lvl 6.  Not to mention I'll likely draw creep aggro.

Any good advice on countering Bloodseeker mid?

Comment: weaver, he can counter bloodseeker's ulti with his ulti

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Countering Bloodseeker is a matter of winning the first few levels before he can get his Bottle. The typical Bloodseeker build is QB+Stout Shield+Healing Salve. Assuming you're a ranged hero, trade as much damage as you can as soon as possible. If he ignores you and goes for last hits, you can pound him harder than he regenerates. After you've done this twice, he's out of regen and too low on health to come to the creep wave. If you're a melee hero, you'll have a bit harder of a time because you'll take a lot of creep damage doing this, but the same concept applies.

If you let him get an early Bottle or Boots or a few extra levels and extra points in Blood Bath, winning the lane becomes significantly harder. Instead, you need to take whatever damage he and the creeps deal to you and harass him for all it's worth, as you can be safe in the knowledge that he has no surprise spells to pull on you (other than a 120 damage DoT which just allows you to hit him harder).

Abuse creep aggro constantly. When the Bloodseeker goes in for last hits, draw the creep aggro on purpose by right clicking him and then backing off. This will cause his creeps to harass you and your creeps to chase those creeps. You can then drop the aggro, step in front of the wave, and deal extra harass damage if he goes for the last hit, or simply mess with his timing and then deny the creep. If he tries to trade with you, just micro well and this is exactly what you want because you have adequate regen where he's relying on a single Salve to last him until his Bottle. As a melee hero, Bloodseeker needs to have a health buffer to go for last hits, because you can kite him as he tries to run out of range and hit him 4-5 times if necessary.

If you're a melee hero, it's a bit different. You have to be equally aggressive in trading harass but you also have to expend mana (if you're a melee hero without a nuke you probably shouldn't be mid in the first place) to force him off the wave. This is actually usually really easy.

Bloodseeker is a very weak hero: his only strength is his Silence which can be useful against heroes that rely on mobility spells. In order to counter him, all you have to do is carry a TP Scroll. If he uses his ultimate on you and there's no tower close by to retreat to, you just TP away. He can't stop you, and has wasted a lot of time and effort ganking that he can't afford to as a carry.

Alternatively, you can just dual lane mid and he automatically loses the lane badly, usually even if an ally comes to make it a 2v2. Specific heroes can also beat Bloodseeker 1v1 without any real effort in solo mid simply because they're much stronger heroes or have strong slows to force him off the creep wave:

- Venomancer
- Viper
- Ancient Apparition
- Tiny
- Sand King (Level E)
- Templar Assassin
- Luna
- Stormspirit
- Lich
- Warlock
- Night Stalker
- Batrider

I'd link to a couple of replays but I literally haven't seen a Bloodseeker in weeks because the hero is just terrible once people learn to always carry TP's.

EDIT: I finally came across a Bloodseeker!

- https://dotabuff.com/matches/59506284

Comment: I would add that the typical Bloodseeker go for 1 level in rage, 2 level in bloodbath and then 2 in thirst. He will gank at 6 and 7. To counter him, just buy wards, tell your teammates to buy tps and call ss in time ...

Answer (score 1):

when going against mid BS, all you have to do is try and deny your creeps as much as possible, that way he loses exp. as well as gold and bloodbath is not much of use to him(although he will also deny his creep wave frequently). also huskar is a very good bloodseeker's counter, early game harass him with your fire, mid game your ulti will do massive dmg also with your fire on so that even if he ruptures you he doesnt have the power to stand and fight or make you run. BS is very easy to counter actually if you can deny a lot as well as last hit properly. hope this helped.
P.S. I used to own with bloodseeker in ranked as well as pub games untill they found tp was a best way to counter. but force staff again cancels your tp so be cautious..

Answer (score 0):

I find venomancer to be an extremely powerful counter to Bloodseeker in mid. Build W -> Q -> W -> Q -> W -> R. Harass him to about half hp with auto attacks, pop your Q and Ulti and finish him.

Answer (score -3):

I'm realy experienced in dota 1. The only thing you have to always remember is to FARM. Don't go for the kill unless he is a noob; just stay out of his way and FARM. The one who farms the most wins the lane.

Comment: when giving negative marks, you should add a comment.

Comment: this aint a negative comment...
this is how pro players roll...

Comment: I think the problem here is that the answer is badly written not very constructive and a bit arrogant.

Comment: i think the whole problem is that the bloodseeker gets more farm than you.  and since he wins the midlane everytime you go there youll just die to him.  so saying go FARM is not easy.