# What is a good way to harrass Bloodseeker in the middle lane?

Tags: dota-2

Bloodseeker is a pain to lane against, because of his passive health regeneration whenever he last hits or denies a creep. I cannot harass him for too long before getting out of sight, because his Q deals decent damage over time (DOT) early game, and his ultimate has significant burst damage. After his ultimate, he will certainly start running towards me, and I die if I run or die if I stand still.

It is incredibly frustrating and I am at a loss about how to counter him.

Comment: Another answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78334/how-do-i-counter-bloodseeker-mid

Comment: Woops! I didn't see it in the suggested box though, when I was posting the question.

Comment: No problem, I think they can be merged somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the lastest patch was just released, it's pretty hard to predict some specific counter versus bloodseeker. However here are some general tips about how the hero works and what weaknesses he has :

- The 2 first levels of bloodbath don't bring much regen. Bloodseeker's players tend to often to go in melee range in order to CS (= creep stats = last hits + denies) thinking that they will regen back : They are **wrong**. When they do that at the very begining of the game you can harass the hell out of them. Make that Bloodseeker understand that going in melee range is not a good idea (for now). When he reaches level 5 it becomes much harder.
- However : To compensate his ability to gain life, his HP pool is pretty low early on so you can still trade with him without much problems
- Out CS him. I mean if you face a Bloodseeker : Last hit and deny and focus to not miss anything. Bloodseeker has a pretty awesome attack animation and some good base damage which make CSing vs him really hard. Grab some cheap stats items (ironwood branch, balde of attack, Wraithband/Null Talisman/Bracers) and if you're melee a quelling blade. Preventing him from gaining life with CS is the easiest way to shut down a Bloodseeker.
- If he goes on you (If he casted Rapture) : don't moove (obviously, press "stop/hold on" key) and trade hit with him. Don't try to run, it's pointless. Man-fighting him is the best way to deal with the problem :

  - If he silences you : Great, you just gained at least 30% damage for
    free, you should use them to autoattack him. Average (and bad) Bloodseeker's players forget to often the side effect of their silence. They will silence you ( = give you free damage) and dive you under your tower : which is a pretty bad idea. You can abuse that to kill them or put them low hp enough to force them back.
  - If he doesn't silence you : use your spells to burst him down quickly which makes diving you under tower a lot scarier.

**Things to keep in mind versus Bloodseeker**

- Since lastest patch he no longer gains armor when thirst is active : if you can force him to come under the tower to kill you, he will probably die before
- Bloodseeker is a momentum based hero : shut him down early and he wont be a problem later in the game. Worst the mid game is for him, worst his lategame will be. Shutting him down is as simple as not giving him kills and Out CSing him (no absolute needs to kill him)
- Bloodseeker is a ganking hero : put wards to see him coming ...
- ... however he does not have **any** disables (appart with expensive items) : Carry a TP  scroll on yourself : if he Raptures  + silences you : just TP back to base and watch him desperately trying to right click you to death while you laught at him.
- He can't forcestaff you to cancel the TP, that doesnt work
- Finally he has no escape (appart from movespeed) : 1 or 2 gank(s) from your supports in early game can ruin the rest of the game for him.

Comment: I like that we wrote basically the same thing 18 months apart. =)

Comment: @Decency oww, I saw 3 upvote and I assumed this wasnt a duplicate ><. Well it seems that Bloodseeker gameplay hasn't evolved in the last 18 months :D. Let's see if this new patch bring some meaningful changes =D